# Getting null value of Name and Price Property and Saving to Mysql using Spring JPARepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing issue regarding getting null value of Name and Price Property and Saving to Mysql using Spring bootJPA using interface JpaRepository. It saved data only cid to mysql db for all other fields saving null for Name and price fields in MySql Db. I am using MySql database.

**POJO Class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE_DTLS")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer cid;
    private String name;
    private Double price;
}
```

**Repo Class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import in.ashokit.binding.Course;

public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Serializable> {

}
```

**Service class**

```
@Service
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepo;

    @Override
    public String upsert(Course course) {

        courseRepo.save(course); // upsert (insert / update based on PK)

        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public Course getById(Integer cid) {
        Optional<Course> findById = courseRepo.findById(cid);

        if (findById.isPresent()) {
            return findById.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Course> getAllCourses() {
        return courseRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteById(Integer cid) {
        if (courseRepo.existsById(cid)) {
            courseRepo.deleteById(cid);
            return "Delete Success";
        } else {
            return "No Record Found";
        }
    }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
public class CourseRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CourseService courseService;

    @PostMapping("/course")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createCourse(@RequestBody Course course) {
        String status = courseService.upsert(course);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(status, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/course/{cid}")
    public ResponseEntity<Course> getCourse(@PathVariable Integer cid) {
        Course course = courseService.getById(cid);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(course, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/courses")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Course>> getAllCourses() {
        List<Course> allCourses = courseService.getAllCourses();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allCourses, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/course")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateCourse(@RequestBody Course course) {
        String status = courseService.upsert(course);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/course/{cid}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteCourse(@PathVariable Integer cid) {
        String status = courseService.deleteById(cid);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What did your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is wrong.

Change this:

```
JpaRepository<Course, Serializable>
```

Like this:

```
JpaRepository<Course, Integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second value in `JpaRepository` should be the type of primary key of the entity class which in your case is Integer. Change `Repo` class as follows:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {

}
```